# How to add a button on NavBar with transparent background in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to add a button on Navigation Bar with transparent background in Xamarin forms.

[Here is the sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQo9e.png)

how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your page you can add this:

```
ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("Back", "backIcon.png", () => 
{Application.Current.MainPage = new RootPage(); }));
```